# WPF ItemsControl with one stack of items

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need in `ItemsControl` that place all `Items` in the same position (0, 0), one stack, like a `Grid` by default if i will not set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`.

Yes i can use `Grid` or `Canvas` but maybe there is some other more primitive control? Or may be there are some styles changes to do so?

I want to bind the collection to `ItemsSource` as usual and rule the position of `Items` by their `Margin` properties. I have done offset logic but in standart `ItemsControl` the `Margin` of the second element is calculating from the end of the first what i want to avoid.

Comment: Use a Grid as the ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Yellow" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the above example the items overlap each other as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "common" solution? This is how you would do this using an ItemsControl.